# Firebase: Fetch Data not working in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a logic where I want to maintain a counter for each User in the firebase realtime data base. When the user encounters the Home Screen I am sending a query to the firebase for the data by invoking an action creator from componentDidMount in my Home component . My idea is that first time when the User encounters the home screen I will add the counter to the database, to understand whether it is first time or not I am expecting a null or false when I am trying to fetch the data. Unfortunately my call back is never getting executed when I am trying to fetch the data.  I can see 'hit loadInitialDbVal' in the console but not 'inside firebase fetch callback'. Let me know if I have missed any steps. I have set up the real time DB and I can see a null there. Below is my action creator.

```
export const loadInitialDbVal = () => {
  console.log('hit loadInitialDbVal');
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('users/')
      .on('value', (snapshot) => {
        console.log('inside firebase fetch callback');
        console.log(snapshot.exist());
        console.log(snapshot.val() + 'value');
        dispatch({type: 'LOAD_INITIAL_DB_VALUES', payload: snapshot.val()});
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors at all in your query.  Something could be going wrong, and you'd never know.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks! I tried catching the error with try catch block but unfortunately nothing is caught.

Comment: try/catch won't work.  You need to attach a callback for that as described in the API documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on

Comment: @DougStevenson hi thanks, that helped, there were some problems with the permission

Comment: OK, you can answer your own question here, or delete the question if you're done with it.